# Switched hosting providers, self-hosted authoritative, messed up MX record

Tags: amazon-s3, mx-record, dns-hosting, amazon-route53

Newbie alert, I'm in a bind but I'm not super familiar with MX record issues.

We used to host our site with a custom hosting provider and recently switched to S3. We have our own authoritative DNS server, which sets our MX records 1,5,10s to the GMAIL domains.

There is something missing from my understanding, as I thought this would be enough to keep continuity with email, but incoming emails are not coming in. We can send out but can't receive emails.

I'm assuming it has something to do with mail.our_domain.com since it points to some random server. Do I need to get route53 involved since we are hosting with S3?

Comment: There's a dozen things you might have gotten wrong, but without an example email address, there's really no way anyone else can check anything.

Comment: The mail subdomain is irrelevent for email delivery, it's all about your MX records. mail subdomain is often for a webmail client or similar. Share your domain name if you want help.

Comment: Can you post teh actual domain?  Also, have you run `dig` looking for your MX records, asking multiple different dns servers for the info?  Did the MX records stay the same from the first provider to the second provider?

Comment: The issue turned out to be the naked domain issue where I was pointing my  naked domain to a CNAME- a bit no-no. Since I was using S3 there is only a CNAME and we used http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect to set up the `A` record as listed on the site.